# How to remove GPS data in image using Camera2?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

In old android camera api, we can remove GPS data in image using this method.([Camera.Parameters -> removeGpsData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#removeGpsData()))

Does anyone know how to remove or disable GPS data in image using new Android Camera2 api? Our goal is to take picture without gps info in image's exif.

The following is my code:

```
private fun createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        val texture = textureView.surfaceTexture

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        val surface = Surface(texture)

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(
                CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
        )
        previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader?.surface),
                object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (cameraDevice == null) return

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        captureSession = cameraCaptureSession
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(previewRequestBuilder)

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build()
                            captureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest,
                                    captureCallback, backgroundHandler)
                        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        activity.showToast("Failed")
                    }
                }, null)
    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
    }

}
```

Comment: whats the code you are using so far?

Comment: Please publish the code which you are using so that we can look at it and suggest changes

Comment: @Jayanth Hi, I just publish the code.

Answer (score 0):

After one day of study, finally find out the solution.

Just set value of this key [JPEG_GPS_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#JPEG_GPS_LOCATION) to null.

```
private var captureRequestBuilder: CaptureRequest.Builder? = null

captureRequestBuilder?.apply {
   set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_GPS_LOCATION, null)
}
```